# dbt Core run : Run only related Models

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

We use dbt Core to run dbt models on snowflake. But when i am running a model with +, its running all the related and some unrelated components.
Assume my components are like this -

```
src1 --\          --> model_tgt_2  
src2 -->model1-->/-->model4-\
src3 -->model2-->model5 ---->model_tgt_1
```

src1 and src 2 are used in model1. Then model1 is used to built model_tgt_2, and model4.
src3 is used to build model2, and model5.
And then model4 and model5 are used to build intended model_tgt_1.

When i am running `dbt run  -s +model_tgt_1`, its running model1,model2,model4,model5,model_tgt_2, and model_tgt_1.

My questions are

- why its running model_tgt_2  when this isnt related in DAG.
- and if its intended, how can skip running strictly unrelated models.

Comment: running `dbt ls --select +model_tgt_1 --resource-type model` should give you a hint of which models (or nodes) are part of the `select` statement. dbt should only be running related models, though

Answer (score 0):

If the [DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx6oA.png) is correct I dont see why `model_tgt_2` would run.
However a couple of things that might help:

- Use `--exclude` to ignore any models you dont want to run.
- Use `n+model_tgt_1` to limit the number of levels you reference. Note `n` can be any number.

Comment: I think when you add +modelX, it will run everything before modelX and whatever pre and post models of anything before modelX. So, even if model_tgt_2 is not directly dependent on model_tgt_1 , it will run it.